# How can I count number of populated consecutive fields in excel?

Tags: excel

Is there a formula that allows me to calculate number of consecutively populated fields until my first blank field.

For example

```
Date   Minutes Worked Out  Consecutive Days Worked Out
======================================================
9/8           25               1
9/9           27               2
9/10          30               3
9/11          0                0
9/12          0                0
9/13          22               1
9/14          15               2
9/15          0                0
```

Notice that my calculation restarts at 1 on 9/13 since the previous day was a 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
=IF(B2>0,SUM(C1)+1,0)
```

.......

```
=IF(B18>0,SUM(C17)+1,0)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The sum of one cell is the same as the value of the cell. Meaning SUM is not needed

Comment: @Andreas if you remove the SUM you will get an error when calculating C2. Sum function ignores text.

Comment: Why would there be text in the cells?

Comment: in first cell you would be adding header

Answer (score 0):

ok just simpley go to coulm E2 and  paste this function

=IF(B:B > 0,1+E1,0)
then drag all the way to end of cloum E

here is example your excel code ready for what you requested with the above function 
by the way just make sure you format the column  B to be numbers and it has valid numbers in it first ... to do that .. right click on column B and select Cell properties from category Tab select numbers and click on .

here is a link to download your file i have done the same fourmala its working for me .. and the function is placed on E2 and the uploaded excel . good luck

[click here to download](http://ftp.sacodeco.net/main.html?download&weblink=fe9ce69b6394b6e46bcb680ee3035bbd&realfilename=New$20Microsoft$20Office$20Excel$20Worksheet.xlsx)